# Include order in *.idl file with JacORB

Tags: java, ant, corba, idl, jacorb

I have one problem with `idl2java ant` task (I'm using org.jacorb.idl.**JacIDL**). This very problem doesn't exist with my **cpp** implementation of generating cpp code form idl files.

I have 3 *.idl files, let's say:

- A.idl
- B.idl
- C.idl

Each one is in folder named after file in psm directory, now:
**A.idl** consists of basic types only,
 **B.idl** includes **A.idl** and also have some basic types, 
 **C.idl** includes **B.idl** and **A.idl** in that **specific order**.

I can't change include order. Building **A** and **B** generates no problem. Building C generates error:

```
[jacorb.idl] ERROR : C.idl, line:16(52): Undefined name:
```

Shifting includes to **A,B** order **instead B,A** resolves problem, but I will repeat myself - **I can't do that for variety of reasons, one of which is fact that cpp implementation besed on ACE library works fine.**
 So I ask politely for you help, because I have no idea if that can be helped. Here's my actual task as bonus - maybe it will help (if there's a typo sorry, it's only here - code 'works').

```
<target name="idlj-generate" depends="idlj-init">
    <idl2java
    srcdir="${psm.dir}/${project}/"
    destdir="${build.generated.dir}"
    packageprefix="com.mypackageprefix"
    includepath="${psm.dir}"
    all="true">
        <define key="__JACORB_GENERATE__"/>
        <define key="globalimport" value="true"/>
    </idl2java>
</target>
```

and for informational purposes working piece:

```
<taskdef name="idl2java" classname="org.jacorb.idl.JacIDL">
    <classpath refid="idlj.classpath"/>
</taskdef>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You would be best asking JacORB questions on the jacorb-developer mailing list.

Could you also clarify what version of JacORB you are using - can you reproduce the problem with 3.6?

You haven't provided sufficient information to state what is undefined.

Have you tried removing the "all" flag and compiling them one at a time ?

Comment: I'm sorry about inconvenience. Please tell me what else do you want to know. I'm using JacORB 2.3.1. Error doesn't reproduce with JacORB 3.6 of which I am glad, but... JacORB 3.6. doesn't support "packageprefix" flag. Migrating will propably destroy backward compatibility of all corba software in my company. Meh, I will look into it. Thank You for answer

Comment: I think for packageprefix you are after i2jpackage? 

Did you try compiling one at a time i.e. removing the all flag ?

Comment: Yes - i2jpackage with argument ":prefix" solved problem with old JacORB flag. Now I'm migrating to JacORB 3.6 as first tests show acceptable amount of work required to change old repositories (mostly problems with java 1.4 jdk compability). Maybe nothing will explode - general tests shall be done tommorrow. Thank you for your help. I was so fixated on implementation I hadn't thought about versions.

Comment: Great! Any problems the JacORB mailing lists are http://www.jacorb.org/contact.html and bugzilla is http://jacorb.org/bugzilla.  
  p.s. if the answer is acceptable would appreciate you resolving/ticking it :-)

Comment: I forgot about marking your answer as resolved. Sorry about that - I'm newbie, this was my first question.

Comment: No problem :-D Hope it helped.